# YII2 Валидаторы

Tags: php, yii2

Не могу понять как работают валидаторы в YII, вот мне приходит пост запрос в контроллер:

```
public function actionAddnewserver()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();    

        $server = new Server();

        $server->insertNewServer($data);
    }
}
```

Перед вставкой в БД я например хочу проверить `$data['url']` на валидность. В этом контроллере имеется вот такой метод:

```
/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // Проверяет, что "website" является корректным URL. Добавляет http:// к атрибуту "website".
        // если у него нет URI схемы
        ['website', 'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http', 'message' => 'ошибка'],
    ];
}
```

Это все что я смог найти из документации. Как я должен понять корректен ли `URL`  или нет? С YII работаю впервые. Ну логически я должен передать эту строку в какой нибудь булевый метод который вернул бы мне `true` или `false` а тут как вообще не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно задать атрибут модели Server и вызвать функцию validate(), которая вернет true, если валидация прошла.

```
public function actionAddnewserver()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();    

        $server = new Server();
        $server->website = $data['website'];

        if($server->validate()){
            $server->insertNewServer($data);
        }else{
            $errors = $server->errors;
        }
    }
}
```

Примерно так. Более подробно смотри тут [Правила валидации](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-models/#validation-rules)

Comment: Подскажите, получается метод rules должен быть в модели server?

Comment: Разобрался. Но мне все равно не понятно. Получается у родительского класса есть метод который дергает метод rules и там дальше уже согласно данных в массиве действует? А как быть если у меня в валидации не только веб сайт и например еще емейл, как понять что метод validate возвращает true именно на том на чем мне надо?

Comment: Он вернет false, если хоть одно правило не пройдет, т.е. true - если все правила выполняются, в переменную $server->errors упадут описания ошибок